# Is there a way to get multiple select values without sorting it in PHP?

Tags: php, multiple-select

I have a multiple select, wherein I need to save it the order in which I selected it. The problem is, the order gets sorted.

```
//This is my multiple select...

<select multiple="multiple" name="sequence[]">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select>

//This is my code in saving it to the database...

foreach($request->sequence_array AS $key=>$value){
  $sequence = new Sequence();
  $sequence->sequence = $value;
  $sequence->save();
}
```

When I select `C, A, B` I need it to save in that order but what I get instead is `A, B, C`.

Comment: No; you're making a single `$_POST` request; there's no way to no the *order* in which the user interacted with the front-end in back-end code. You could work this out using JavaScript though, and make multiple POST request through AJAX.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll just do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot expect the result the way you want.

If you do not want to change interface logic and keep the current form, all you can do is to add some javascript over it (you can use jQuery or any other tool for your choice) and save order of user select activity into another hidden form field.

Then on back end you can analyze user activity and make a decision about the order. In your case if you see that user simply selected C, A, and then B it will be easy to build the sequence. However if user selected something on and off several times, it will be harder issue

Comment: I think I'll just have to change my interface logic. Thanks!